# C - What is wrong with my memory freeing function?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, free

I have a struct which contains 2 integers and a pointer to another struct. I allocate memory for struct first and then for the pointer. When I free the memory I free up the pointer first and then I free up the struct.

When I run my program and call the function that frees memory it crashes when the call is made. When I don't call the function that frees memory it works fine, but then I'm not freeing up the memory.

I tried removing the line that frees the memory allocated to the pointer and the program doesn't crash, but I don't think thats right since a "free" is needed for every "malloc/calloc" right? Anyone see anything wrong with the freeing function?

```
//Define a struct data type
struct q_element
{
    //Declaration of struct members
    int element;
    int priority;
    struct q_element *next_element;
};

//Method to allocate memory
struct q_element* allocateStruct()
{
    //Declaration of a variable
    struct q_element *e;

    //Allocate memory for one queue element
    e = malloc(sizeof(struct q_element));

    //Allocate memory for one pointer to a queue element
    e->next_element = calloc(1,sizeof(struct q_element*));

    //Initialize integer members of queue element
    e->element = 0;
    e->priority = 0;

    return e;
}

//Method to free memory allocated
void freeStruct(struct q_element* e)
{
    //Free up pointer member
    free(e->next_element);

    //Free up struct
    free(e);
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean applying `freeStruct` recursively  on `e->next_element` instead of `free` (but it should be tail recursion).

Comment: Are you sure that you do not use freed memory after the deallocation? But your structure is suspiciously similar to some linked list(queue?) item where such allocation-deallocation may become a source of problems.

Comment: `e->next_element = calloc(1,sizeof(struct q_element*));` --> `e->next_element = NULL;` , `free(e->next_element);free(e);` --> `if(e){freeStruct(e->next_element);free(e);}`

Comment: Nothin wrong with the function itself if you only free one structure. But my guess is that these are used to form a list, and your code to free the whole list is wrong, but since it isn't here, we can't see it.

Comment: yes it is for a priority q queue and whenever i pop the highest priority element in the queue I call the `freeStruct` function in order to free the memory the popped element occupied.. i only free one at a time, not the whole list in one for loop @LeeDanielCrocker

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i cant make out your code as it is all on the same line.. do you mean the code on left of --> for code on right of it?

Comment: But freeing one structure probably breaks the list, causing it to contain pointers to freed memory, which will eventually lead to a crash. WIthout your "add" and "remove" functions, there's no way to know.

Comment: i change the pointers before i free up the memory.. it all works fine when i removed the  free function when it wasnt working.. @LeeDanielCrocker

Comment: Still, you can't treat the structures individually. You have to allocate and free them as demanded by the larger meta-structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to allocate memory for the `next_element` pointer. The pointer is already there, just like `int element` for example.

So if you want to allocate just one element, you can set the `next_element` pointer to `NULL` and everything is fine.

Comment: Indeed, you only set a value for `next_element` when you have *another* struct to link.

Comment: ...because if you allocate memory right now for the next `struct` you have the problem of what do you do with `next_element` in *that* `struct`, and so on.

Comment: so i don't need to allocate memory for the pointer and hence dont need to free it after? which data types need further allocating when allocating memory for structs then? i remember when i had a struct with a string i had to allocate memory for the string aswell.. ints and pointers dont require, strings do require, what else?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to allocate memory for the pointer, and you don't need to free it. All things that are 'allocated statically', like `something mything;` don't need `free`, and all things that are 'allocated dynamically` like `something *mything = malloc(...` need `free`

Comment: In the last example, `something *mything = malloc(...` you actually have 2 things, the pointer, which is allocated statically, and the thing itself, which is allocated dynamically.

Comment: yes i understand, but which other data types require dynamic allocation using malloc? arrays only?

Comment: In almost all cases, you can choose if you want to allocate statically or dynamically. `int arr[20];` is a statically allocated array, `int* arr = malloc(20*sizeof(int));` is a dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 4):

You are not allocating enough memory for `e->next_element` in the line:

```
e->next_element = calloc(1,sizeof(struct q_element*));
                                             //  ^^^ remove the *
```

That should be:

```
e->next_element = calloc(1,sizeof(struct q_element));
```

If you used `e->next_element` as though it were a valid pointer, you most likely ended up accessing memory that you did not allocate. That clobbered some of the bookkeeping information created by `calloc`, which lead to problems when you called `free`.

Comment: i only want to allocate memory for a pointer to a struct, not a whole struct

Comment: @Yiannis, the `struct` already has pointer. The pointer can be NULL or it needs to point to a `struct`. It does not make sense to allocate memory for a pointer only and assign that to `e->next_element`.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
//Allocate memory for one pointer to a queue element
e->next_element = calloc(1,sizeof(struct q_element*));
```

you allocate space for a pointer to a q_element structure, rather than a q_element structure. Do you attempt to write to this structure, because if so, that's probably where it goes wrong.

As a side note you might be better off just doing

```
e->next_element = 0
```

inside `allocate_struct` and then doing `e->next_element = allocate_struct()` outside the function later.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what everyone else is mentioning about allocation, you also need a sentinel to check if the next_element was already freed. You may be attempting a double free.

Try the following code:

```
void freeStruct(struct q_element* e)
{
    //Free up pointer member
    if(e->next_element != 0){
        free(e->next_element);
        e->next_element = 0;
    }

    //Free up struct
    free(e);
}
```

Comment: Calling `free` with a null pointer does nothing and is perfectly safe.

Comment: @alain: Yes, but after `free`, the pointer is not guaranteed to point to `NULL`. So while the `if` is unnecessary, the `e->next_element = NULL;` would still be a good idea, in my opinion.

Comment: i will only be freeing one q_element at a time, one for each pop

Comment: Yes, setting freed pointers to `NULL` is a good idea and makes the code safer.

Comment: but since i dont need to free the pointer separate do i just set it to `NULL` before i free the whole struct?

Comment: i tried doing that but it crashes again.. i set the pointer to null and then free the whole struct in the next line @alain

Comment: @Yiannis, you can set it to `NULL` in `allocateStruct()`, replace `e->next_element = calloc(...` with `e->next_element = NULL;`

Comment: @alain yes i do that aswell.. i thought you said after i free it it is not guaranteed to be `NULL` so it is a good idea to set it to `NULL` after i free it

Comment: Yes, but that's only useful when there is a chance that you may access the pointer later, but because `e` is freed too, it's not needed there.

Comment: i set the pointer to `NULL` before the call to the `freeStruct()` function and it works..

Comment: ohh so there is no point setting it to NULL before the call then? @alain

Comment: What I meant is: In *general* it's a good idea, but here there is no point in setting `e->next_element = NULL;`, because `e` is freed too.